# os.path.isfile return a False when using in django rest framework, while it works fine in ipython for the same file path

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write a function to calculate a file's md5,it works fine in ipython(`python manage.py shell`),but when using in django model's `FileField` to get the uploaded file's md5,the code `os.path.isfile(filepath)` return False ,I am sure that this path is a file's path.I am confused ,please help me,thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using the file's absolute path? If not, then differences in current working directory explain the problem.

Comment: Yes ,it's an absolute path,this is my screenshots [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hgHdM8REVRa1Z5YUxNUDVMUzA/view?usp=sharing)  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hgHdM8REVRU1l6U0ZrZ2xZSms/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be trying to access the file while it's not yet saved in the uploaded directory.
Django has a [documentation section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/) explaining how to deal with `FileField`.

Comment: OK,get it ,thank you very much,I have known how it happens . And now I need to do this,I am using django rest framework to write rest api.I have a model which contains several fields , a `FileField` and a `CharField` to store the uploaded file's md5.I overrided the model's save() function,i want to get the uploaded file's md5 before super.save() is called,but failed.Would you please give me an advice to do this?